# How to find the expected value of the random sum of variables?

Tags: calculus, probability, expectation

> $X$ is a discrete random variable with the following density function:
>   $$
>     f_X(n)
>   = \begin{cases}
>         c e^{-2} \, \frac{2^n}{n!}
>       & n \geq 0, \\
>         c 3^n
>       & n < 0.
>     \end{cases}
> $$
>   Define the variables $V$ as follows:
>   $$
>     V
>   = \begin{cases}
>         0
>       & X < 0 \\
>         X
>       & X \geq 0.
>     \end{cases}
> $$
>   Let $V_1, V_2, V_3, \dotsc$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables each having the same distribution as $V$.
>
> Let $N$ be a poisson random variable with mean $5$.
>   Assume $N$ is independent of the $V_i$’s.
>   Define $Z = \sum_{i=1}^N V_i$.
>   What is $E(Z)$?
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvAtW.png).)

$C$ is a constant

Not a homework. The whole problem (but not very relevant) could be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885578/find-the-expected-value-of-the-sum-of-random-variables

---

$\mathbb E[V]=\sum_{n\geq 0}nce^{-2}2^n/n!=2c$

The $\mathbb E[N]$ is given as $5$.

So the answer is $\mathbb E[V]\mathbb E[N]=10c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that: $$\mathbb E[Z\mid N=n]=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^nV_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb EV_i=n\mathbb EV$$Here the first equality is a consequence of independence of $N$ and the $V_i$.

Based on this we find $\mathbb E[Z\mid N]=N\mathbb EV$ and consequently:

$$\mathbb EZ=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Z\mid N]]=\mathbb E[N\mathbb EV]=\mathbb EV\mathbb EN$$

I leave the rest (i.e. finding $\mathbb EV$ and $\mathbb EN$)   to you.

Comment: Well played!!!! $\mathbb EV$ is $2c$ and $\mathbb EN$ is 5? (updated in the question)

Comment: I have not learnt that $\mathbb EX =\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y]]$ but I believe you are correct (of course). Thank you again